# How to load modules from specific directory in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I've a python script which I'm executing on Master node using spark-shell. This script is using some user defined modules, specifically another scripts. But when I run the script on local system, and import the modules, then it is not throwing any kind of exception. But when I'm executing the script in spark environment, it is throwing exception like module not found. I've also tried something like below, but that is also not working on spark cluster.
sys.path.append('')
import

Can someone please assist me how can I do work around modules in pyspark.
I'm using python 2.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code dependencies are not available in the executors. You need to instruct pyspark to distribute your source files so they are available. You can include single files using the method `addPyFile` of your context. Check the documentation here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html